# Questions about the pairwise markov property

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, conditional-probability

Consider a graph $G =(V,E)$ and let the family of random variables $X=(X_v)_{v\in V}$ be a Markov Random Field with respect to $G$. Then we know that for any two vertices $\{u,v\}\subset V$ that are not adjacent, the pairwise Markov property holds, that is
$$
X_u \perp \!\!\! \perp X_v | X_{V\setminus\{u,v\}}.
$$
For any vertex $w \in V\setminus\{u,v\}$ do we have that
$$
X_u \perp \!\!\! \perp X_v | X_w
$$
always holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not necessarily true. Consider a graph with $V=\{u,v,w,o\}$ with edges $E=\{(u,o), (v,o), (w,o)\}$.

```
u--o--v
   |
   w
```

If $X_u=X_v=X_o$ is independent of $X_w$, then this satisfies the Markov Random Field assumptions. But $X_u$ and $X_v$ are not conditionally independent given $X_w$.

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit more please?